# Why recursive type raising the mypy error in assigment sentences?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a this piece of code:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

MatList: TypeAlias = list["MatList"] | list[float]


def convert(x: MatList)-> MatList:
    if isinstance(x[0], float):
        reveal_type(x)
        x[0] = 1.2
    return x

a: MatList = [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
print(convert(a))
```

mypy 0.991 raises the errors:

```
test_mypy.py:8: note: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.list[...], builtins.list[builtins.float]]"
test_mypy.py:9: error: No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "float"  [call-overload]
test_mypy.py:9: note: Possible overload variants:
test_mypy.py:9: note:     def __setitem__(self, SupportsIndex, MatList, /) -> None
test_mypy.py:9: note:     def __setitem__(self, slice, Iterable[MatList], /) -> None
test_mypy.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[List[float]]", variable has type "MatList")  [assignment]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I expect after the `isinstance` sentence the reveal_type `builtins.list[builtins.float]` and the assignment will pass without mypy errors.
I also expect variable `a` to be read by mypy as `MatList`

What i do wrong?

Comment: `mypy` does not infer by item type, and so your `isinstance` check does not affect `mypy` type. You can use a custom `TypeGuard` like `def is_float_sequence(seq: object) -> TypeGuard[Sequence[float]]: ...` and call it instead of `isinstance`.

Comment: And for `list` recursive alias you're facing a variance issue (so `Sequence` should work, if you don't need modification, and otherwise you're in trouble)